# Android ListView Returning Null

Tags: android, listview, android-widget, android-activity

I'm setting up a simple list view with no real data being populated to it yet. However, when trying to run to test I get a null pointer exception every time. I can't figure out whats causing the problem. The error log complains about the setLayoutParams. Here is my code:

```
public class Groups extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.groups_listviews);

        ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view_1);
        lView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, R.layout.groups_listviews_row));
        lView.setCacheColorHint(0);
        lView.setAdapter(null);
        lView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
```

Logcat:

```
06-20 11:03:27.044: D/dalvikvm(3641): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 64K, 43% free 3080K/5379K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 81ms
06-20 11:03:28.388: D/dalvikvm(3641): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 6K, 43% free 3096K/5379K, external 4457K/4816K, paused 28ms
06-20 11:03:28.442: D/AndroidRuntime(3641): Shutting down VM
06-20 11:03:28.442: W/dalvikvm(3641): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com/com.main.Groups}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1696)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at com.main.Groups.onCreate(Groups.java:23)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
06-20 11:03:28.442: E/AndroidRuntime(3641):     ... 11 more
```

Answer: I was accessing the listview of the incorrect layout file (list_view_1), thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the error complains about the setLayoutParams, than usually it is the receiver of the method (aka the ListView) which is null.

I would check if

```
ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view_1);
```

returns null.

Comment: It looks like this is returning null, I will look into list_view_1.

Comment: Got it, this was it, apparently i was accessing the listview (list_view_1) of a different layout file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: it is actually quite a good pattern to look on null pointer exceptions: look at the receiving object and think about if that could be null, in most of the cases, that is what the error message wanted to say ;)

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a `null` to your `setAdapter()` method, that is resulting in the `NullPointerException`.

```
lView.setAdapter(null);
```

A [`setAdapter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) needs a valid `ListAdapter` as it's parameter.

[Here's](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_adapterintro) an example.

If you really need an empty ListView just set the data set on your Adapter to be empty/null instead of setting the adapter to be null.

---

EDIT:

If this isn't causing the problem, then the only other component that can throw a `NullPointerException` can be your `ListView`.

```
ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view_1);
```

Check to see if there is indeed a `ListView` that goes by that ID in your xml.

Comment: +1. Just to add to this. If you really need an empty ListView just set the data set on your Adapter to be empty/null instead of setting the adapter to be null.

Comment: @Kazekage Gaara I don't think so I made listView and setAdapter(null) and no exception thrown. I don't argue that setAdapter(null) is good thing I'm just saying it's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Amal can you update your question with the crash log? That will help us along more

Comment: @Amal That isn't likely going to be the case.

Comment: @dymmeh I didn't has crash at all when I tried to create list and then setAdapter with null I was talking about jamesar problem.

Comment: `listView.setAdapter(null)` is valid, and he said that the problem comes from `setLayoutParams()`. The other answer is more likely to solve the problem.

Comment: @Dalmas I couldn't be certain without seeing the logcat. And this struck to me as the first problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I got the error. The parameter for `new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, gravity)` and instead of specifying the Gravity you are specifying some kind of a layout.

Change the last parameter using an int to specify Gravity (eg. `Gravity.CENTER`) and your problem may be solved.

Comment: I ended up removing the layoutParams entirely, thanks though! :)